# how to get key based on values without any duplicate

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have a situation where i want to get only key and its time determination i,e `am` or `pm`

**here is my data**

```
    var  amUserDate = {"monday|am":false,"tuesday|am":true,"wednesday|am":false,"thursday|am":false,"friday|am":false,"saturday|am":true,"sunday|am":false};

   var   pmUserDate = {"monday|pm":true,"tuesday|pm":false,"wednesday|pm":false,"thursday|pm":false,"friday|pm":false,"saturday|pm":false,"sunday|pm":true};
```

**my desired output:**

based on `true`(value) of `key => value` pair  result would look like this

```
amAvailibility  = [{"day":"tuesday","time":"am"},{"day":"saturday","time":"am"}];


pmAvailibility  = [{"day":"monday","time":"pm"},{"day":"sunday","time":"pm"}];
```

please help me thanks in advance!!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a way of doing that.

```js
var amUserDate = {"monday|am":false,"tuesday|am":true,"wednesday|am":false,"thursday|am":false,"friday|am":false,"saturday|am":true,"sunday|am":false};
var pmUserDate = {"monday|pm":true,"tuesday|pm":false,"wednesday|pm":false,"thursday|pm":false,"friday|pm":false,"saturday|pm":false,"sunday|pm":true};

function fn(obj){
    return Object.keys(obj)
           .filter(key => obj[key])
           .reduce((acc, key) => {
              var splittedKey = key.split("|");
              acc.push({day:splittedKey[0], time:splittedKey[1]});
              return acc;
          }, []);
}

var am = fn(amUserDate);
var pm = fn(pmUserDate);

console.log(am);
console.log(pm)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this code to achieve what you want:

```js
 var  amUserDate = {"monday|am":false,"tuesday|am":true,"wednesday|am":false,"thursday|am":false,"friday|am":false,"saturday|am":true,"sunday|am":false};

var pmUserDate = {"monday|pm":true,"tuesday|pm":false,"wednesday|pm":false,"thursday|pm":false,"friday|pm":false,"saturday|pm":false,"sunday|pm":true};

var amKeys = Object.keys(amUserDate),
    pmKeys = Object.keys(pmUserDate),
    amAvailibility = [],
    pmAvailibility = [];

amKeys.forEach(function(key, index){
   var obj = {};
   if(amUserDate[key]){
     var splitStr = key.split('|');
     obj = {day: splitStr[0], time: splitStr[1] }
     amAvailibility.push(obj);
   }
});

pmKeys.forEach(function(key, index){
   var obj = {};
   if(pmUserDate[key]){
     var splitStr = key.split('|');
     obj = {day: splitStr[0], time: splitStr[1] }
     pmAvailibility.push(obj);
   }
});

console.log(amAvailibility);
console.log(pmAvailibility);
```

Answer (score 0):

iterate over the objects using `for...in` and using an if condition push objects to a new array.

```js
var  amUserDate = {"monday|am":false,"tuesday|am":true,"wednesday|am":false,"thursday|am":false,"friday|am":false,"saturday|am":true,"sunday|am":false};

var   pmUserDate = {"monday|pm":true,"tuesday|pm":false,"wednesday|pm":false,"thursday|pm":false,"friday|pm":false,"saturday|pm":false,"sunday|pm":true};

function transformObject(obj){
   var arr =[];
   for(var key in obj){
      var time = key.replace(/.*\|/,"");
      if(obj[key])
        arr.push({"date": key.replace(/\|.*/, ""), "time":time});
   }

   return arr;
}

var amAvailibility = transformObject(amUserDate), pmAvailibility = transformObject(pmUserDate);

console.log(amAvailibility);
console.log(pmAvailibility);
```